# Многопользовательский чат на C#

Tags: c#, сокет, чат

Добрый день.

Может кто подскажет, как должен функционировать сервер.
Я вижу этот процесс так :  у сервера есть список всех сокетов(клиентов) и клиентов сервер обрабатывает (добавляет в лист, принимает сообщения) в потоке.
Еще вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы сервер принимал сообщения, когда клиент находится на другом ПК в локальной сети.
Спасибо

P.S. Как сделать так , что у меня 1 сервер и много клиентов работают , подключенных к нему (протокол , общая организация) Все примеры в интернетах, которые  видел, сделаны на основе UDP и без серверной части. (клиент-клиент) 
Код. Сервер (запускается в потоке)

```
            IPEndPoint endPoint =  new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localIP), port);
            serverSocket.Bind(endPoint);
            while (true)
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int lengthOfBytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                EndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                do
                {
                    lengthOfBytes = serverSocket.ReceiveFrom(data,ref remoteIP);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(data, 0, lengthOfBytes));
                } while (serverSocket.Available > 0);

                fullRemoteIp = remoteIP as IPEndPoint;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1} : {2} ", fullRemoteIp.Address.ToString(), fullRemoteIp.Port.ToString(), builder.ToString());

                data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Доставлено");
                serverSocket.SendTo(data, remoteIP);
```

Клиент. Клиент(Отправка по клику кнопки)

```
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIP), Port);
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
        try
        {
            client.Connect(endPoint);
            commonWindow.Text += "Отправка" + Environment.NewLine;
            Int32 lengthInBytes = 0;  
            Byte[] data = new Byte[256]; 
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messageWindow.Text);
            lengthInBytes = client.Send(data);
            data = new Byte[256];

            do
            {
                lengthInBytes = client.Receive(data);
                builder.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(data));
            } while (client.Available > 0);

            if (lengthInBytes != 0)
            {
                commonWindow.Text += builder.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

Comment: самый простой и быстрый в написании вариант: WCF+TcpBinding. Не считая времени на знакомство с технологией, сервер и клиент в консольном исполнении пишутся минут за 20 с отладкой.

Comment: @rdorn сервер и клиент на TCP есть, беда в том , что на 1 клиента и по локальной сети не передает(сначала состояние `myClientSocket.Connected ==  true` , потом делаю отправку, которая до сервера не доходит, и состояние переходит в `false`)

Comment: вы не поняли, TcpBinding - один из доступных протоколов для WCF, просто он предоставляет большую интерактивность. что актуально для чата. Никаких сокетов и ручного управления ими, почти все из коробки. А по вашему клиенту и серверу нужен код, тогда можно будет посмотреть что не так

Comment: стоп. во-первых есть кнопка [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/638197/edit), добавьте код в вопрос и хотя бы минимально отформатируйте. В комментариях код писать не нужно

Comment: во-вторых, постарайтесь оставить только необходимый минимум, чтобы вашу проблему можно было воспроизвести

Comment: @rdorn  добавил сервер и клиент, надеюсь понятно

Comment: `LocalIP` на клиенте чему равен? по идее должен быть равен адресу сервера

Comment: @rdorn да , адресу сервера. если я все правильно понял, то адрес сервера равен адресу пк ( где сервер) в локальной сети. Порт равен порту, который указан на сервере (в моем случае 10000)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55189/discussion-between-rdorn-and-mikhail-znak).

Answer (score 1):

В отдельном потоке ставишь прослушку на порт (Для того что бы программа не висла в ожидании сообщения). И все это дело зацикливаешь. Когда сообщение пришло выкидываешь его в чат. А на счет сервера. Используй UDP трансляцию. Все кто подключится к серверу будут получать трансляцию всех сообщений которые были высланы на сервер.

Comment: а как послать сообщение всем? просто по списку пройтись и каждому отправить или бродкастом как то можно?

Comment: если использовать udp-бродкаст, тогда зачем сервер? логи переписки собирать можно таким же клиентом с минимальной правкой логики. К тому же, если сеть сегментирована, то такой чат будет работать только внутри своего сегмента.